Does the app's performance improve when we launch it on the Play Store?
I am developing an Android app using Kotlin and Compose. When I run it from Android Studio on an actual device, it takes 1-2 seconds to display data after starting.
Will the performance increase or decrease when I launch/release it on the Play Store?

That will depend a lot on what is taking the time. Your composables will improve in performance in release mode and after having run on the device for a few times.

Thank you for your comment. I believe most of the time is taken by Room queries. As I'm new to Android development, is there a way to check how much time each operation is taking?

There is quite a bit of documentation on how to inspect your app's performance.

App bundles are generally more optimised than APKs, but still, it depends. You can refer to this for more details. If your API or some other service is taking 1-2 seconds, then obviously there won't be much difference, but if some animation or a UI component is causing that delay, then yes, performance will be better.
You should consider profiling your app to know the exact issue. You can check this to profile your app.
